# UIAlertView Ok button not visible

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Following is the code I am using to create an AlertView. But the Ok button is not visible.

```
 UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset Password" 
                                                     message:@"\n\n" // IMPORTANT
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                           otherButtonTitles:OTHER_BUTTON_OK, nil];

    prompt.tag=RESET_PASSWORD;
    txtOldPwd = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
    [txtOldPwd setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txtOldPwd setPlaceholder:@"Old Password"];
    txtOldPwd.text=@"";
    [prompt addSubview:txtOldPwd];
    [txtOldPwd release];

    txtNewPwd = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 80.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
    [txtNewPwd setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txtNewPwd setPlaceholder:@"New Password"];
    txtNewPwd.text=@"";
    [prompt addSubview:txtNewPwd];
    [txtNewPwd release];

    txtConfirmPwd = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 110.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
    [txtConfirmPwd setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txtConfirmPwd setPlaceholder:@"Confirm Password"];
    txtConfirmPwd.text=@"";
    [prompt addSubview:txtConfirmPwd];
    [txtConfirmPwd release];

    [prompt show];

    [prompt release];
```

I am adding a screenshot of what I am getting.

[image]

**Update**

I just discovered that button is actually there. Height of Alert is too less. A very little portion of button is visible. I tried [this approach](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1722125?start=0&tstart=0) but the button is still not visible. Although the height of alert increases.

Comment: screenshot shows that the button is there but your textfields are covering it up...!! thats why adding "\n" have resolved what you were facing..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

increase the \n ok

```
UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset Password" 
                                                     message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" // IMPORTANT
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

update your code on these lines:

```
cancelButtonTitle:OTHER_BUTTON_OK 
otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

hay Nitish you can try with this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Reset Password"
                          message:@"\n\n" 
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

I hope It will work. Let me know if any clarification needed.

Comment: It workiing Nag_iphone . In my all project I use in this way. Just put what ever I give. and let me know what happened

Comment: I m getting same output after using u r code also but changing the delegate wat makes difference...

Comment: copy the entire nitish  code and check it also put into the u r alert view see the difference